# How to get domain controller IP Address

Tags: c#, networking, active-directory, network-programming

How do you get the Domain Controller IP address programmatically using `C#`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks All,

I done it as in this code

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
    using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
public doIt()
        {
            DirectoryContext mycontext = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain,"project.local");
            DomainController dc = DomainController.FindOne(mycontext);
            IPAddress DCIPAdress = IPAddress.Parse(dc.IPAddress);
        }
```

Thanks again

Comment: To retrieve this across a different domain, you'd need to do: `new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain,"project.local","validUserInDomain","validUserPassword");`

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I would do it.

You'll need to use System.Net and System.DirectoryServices.

```
// get root of the directory data tree on a directory server
DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://rootDSE");
// get the hostname of the directory server of your root (I'm assuming that's what you want)
string dnsHostname = dirEntry.Properties["dnsHostname"].Value.ToString();
IPAddress[] ipAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(dnsHostname);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well here is the general workflow of how to get it as described at the MS site:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247811

Here is the link from PInvoke.net to call the referenced **DsGetDcName** function:

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/DsGetDcName.html

You could go down and dirty and do a raw DNS A Record query as described in the first link, but I think the PInvoke call should do the trick.

Hope that helps,

Mike

Comment: Haven't tried it in C#, but in Java it's real easy to go the DNS A record route.