# Get IP addresses from Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have been able to get computer names from Active directory.

```
var ldap = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://mydomain.pk");
var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(ldap) { Filter = "(objectClass=computer)" };

foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
{
    string str = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Name.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Is there any way to get IP addresses from Active Directory?

Comment: Please have a look at [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/523692/3814721). This might help you.

Comment: Yes, that;s correct!